# Swap Wordpress "Widget Area" based on Page Template

Tags: functions, widgets

i'm using 3 widget areas in my child theme's footer.

i created a secondary custom theme successfully, and am hoping i can simply change those 3 widget area's out in the second theme.

"**Footer - Column 1**" would change to "**Alt Footer - Column 1**"
"**Footer - Column 2**" would change to "**Alt Footer - Column 2**"
"**Footer - Column 3**" would change to "**Alt Footer - Column 3**"

*(and yes, i've already created in WP admin > Appearnace > Widgets, those 3 new custom widget areas, & put temp text widgets in them for now).*

i'm using this in "functions.php" to change the "**Menu**"...

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'respect_menu_swap' );
function respect_menu_swap( $args = '' ) 
{
    if(is_page_template('template-respect.php') && $args['menu_id'] == 'avia-menu') 
    {
        $args['menu'] = '16';
    } 
    return $args;
}
```

**...am hoping for something similar to change each of those "widget areas".**

i've searched, read, searched, & read a LOT trying to figure this out & just can't seem to grasp what should go in place of the menu terms in that code bit. i really struggle with PHP, so would greatly appreciate specific explanation & code:-)

and, i'm saying "**Widget Area**" *instead* of "**Widgets**" because i realized that "Widgets" are *INSIDE* the "Widget Areas". i'd like to swap the whole area instead of just the widget so my people can add/remove various widgets in those 3 "areas" in the WP > Appearance > Widgets admin page as needed. it’s my understanding that if i just use the “Widget ID” then when someone changes which widget(s) are in one of those widget areas, it won’t update on the sites front-end without me changing those ID’s first. i’d like to avoid having to do that if possible.

(BTW: i'm using the [Enfold](https://kriesi.at) WP theme, if that matters)

Answer (score 1):

WOW!
well, it would *seems* as tho i figured it out!

after MORE searching, i came across https://learn.wordpress.org/lesson-plan/widget-areas

apparently i had to "register" a "sidebar" - which thru me, as i was wanting to modify in the footer. after looking *that* up, the term "sidebar" is used anywhere the theme allows the user to add widgets in. and since the Enfold theme footer allows for widgets, i had to "register_sidebar" and THEN modify a line in the template.
i also didn't understand why i had to "register" the "widget area's" at all, thinking that just by creating the custom widgets in WP admin > Appearance > Widgets, that should do it, but no. ya gotta create them there and *ALSO* register them in the child functions too.

so after reading that wordpress page (linked above), i started hunting around in the main Enfold theme files, trying to find something similar. since apparently, some things are named differently than in other themes, which is why my copy/pasting of examples i found elsewhere didn't work.
i found it in... **`themes > enfold > includes > admin > register-widget-area.php`**

so i combined what that wordpress link offered with the footer widget registration and came up with this code that i put in my **child functions.php**...

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'MYWIDGETAREA' );
function MYWIDGETAREA() 
{
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Respect Footer - Column ' . $i,
        'id'            => 'espect_foot_widget_' . $i,
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget clearfix %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '<span class="seperator extralight-border"></span></section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>'
    ));
}
```

in the array, i only changed the "name" & "id", leaving the rest so the structure matches the original theme.

then i went to my **template-custom.php** and found this line...

```
if( ! ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && dynamic_sidebar( 'Footer - Column ' . $i ) ) )
```

...and replaced it with...

```
if( ! ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && dynamic_sidebar( 'Respect Footer - Column ' . $i ) ) )
```

AMAZING!!!

well hopefully all this may benefit someone else in a similar position some day.